# CSS class only applying to one element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have some code that unpacks an array and returns an array of JSX elements. This works fine, however, when one element is clicked, the "selectedEl" css class is removed from all other elements.

I'm pretty sure I've just made some stupid mistake but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

Code that unpacks the array and assigns onClick method:

```
function UnpackReccArray() {
        const renderArray = []
        for (let renderEl = 0; renderEl < self.state.capMethod; renderEl++) {
            renderArray.push(
                <span className="topicElement" onClick={self.pushToChosen.bind(this, self.state.reccDataQuery[renderEl].topicID, renderEl + "topicEl")} id={renderEl + "topicEl"}>
                    <p className="fontLibre">{self.state.reccDataQuery[renderEl].displayName}</p>
                </span>
            )
            if (renderEl + 1 === self.state.capMethod) {
                return (
                    <self.ResultRender title="Popular Subjects" renderContent={renderArray} />
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Code that handles onClick function

```
pushToChosen = (id, elID) => {
    const self = this
    const localChoseArray = this.state.subjectChosenArray
    const index = localChoseArray.indexOf(id.toString())
    if (index > -1) {
        localChoseArray.splice(index, 1);
        self.setState({
            subjectChosenArray: localChoseArray
        }, () => {
            document.getElementById(elID).classList.remove("selectedEl")
        })
    } else {
        self.setState({
            subjectChosenArray: [...this.state.subjectChosenArray, id.toString()]
        }, () => {
            document.getElementById(elID).classList.add("selectedEl")
        })
    }
    document.getElementById(elID).classList.toggle("selectedEl")
}
```

[GIF of the code in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZFOK.gif)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i didn't fully understand the code but it seems that the toggle is what causing the issue since the if and else handles all possible cases , toggle is probably going to do the opposite of the if else bloc .

Comment: From what I understand, toggle is purely CSS based and is only effected by the element itself. Nevertheless I tried switching to classList.add and classList.remove in the if else cases but there was no change in the output. Thanks anyway